# How to Add interstitial ad in changing screens project Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I have looked at many tutorials on how to add Interstitial ads into libgdx. But all of them use constructors which pass in a interface.

I have created my game which changes screen. 
My Classes are:
(in AndroidLauncher:  Initialize(new GameChanger(),config) )

GameChanger extends Game... (setscreen Mainmenu)---->

Mainmenu that implement screen and have constructor that pass in Gamechanger... (setscreen MyGDXGame) -->

MyGDXGame that implement screen and have constructor that pass in Gamechanger -->... (setscreen End)

(I need to show the ad here between MyGdxGame and End)

End that implement screen and have constructor that pass in Gamechanger

Is there a way to add ads between the two screens without using constructor 
or is there a different way?

Please respond?
Sorry for any code and grammar mistakes.
Thanks

This is my AndroidLauncher:

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new Gamekeeper(),config);
}
```

}

This is my GameKeeper class, it extends Game:
public class Gamekeeper extends Game{

```
public SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    this.setScreen(new MainMenu(this));
}
@Override
public void render(){
    super.render();
}
@Override
public void dispose(){
    batch.dispose();
}
```

}

This is my MainMenu class, it implements Screen:

```
protected MainMenu(Gamekeeper gam) {
    game = gam;
batch = new SpriteBatch();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

}

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    backgroundSound.setLooping(true);
    backgroundSound.play();
    backgroundSprite.draw(batch);
    titleFont.draw(batch, title, playButton.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 100);
    scoreFont.draw(batch, "Top Score: " + score, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3 - 20, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + 30);
    playButton.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if(play.contains(screenX,screenY)){
       buttonClick.play();
        backgroundSound.stop();
        mainTheme.setLooping(true);
        mainTheme.play();
       play.setPosition(-500,-500);
       game.setScreen(new MyGdxGame(game));
    }
    return true;
}
```

The other classes are mostly similar

Comment: please post more of your code, and also you can edit your post to update your code format.

Comment: Wat type of more code do u need?? Eg. Android launcher codes or class codes.

Comment: Anything that will help us help you

Comment: This is my Android Launcher:

Comment: public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication{

    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
  initialize(new Gamekeeper(),config);
 }
}

Comment: Please edit your post and format your code thanks

Comment: Include your code snippet when you edit

Comment: can u help me please

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem to add Intersitial Ads by implementing interface. Create interface file in youre core project folder.

```
public interface PlayServices
{
....//some other playservices methods;
public void showOrLoadInterstital();
}
```

in AdnroidLauncher.java class implement the created PlayServices interface.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements PlayServices {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    adView = new InterstitialAd(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(YOUR ID OF ADMOB);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
           //all of these toasts added for the debug reason, after successfully
           //implementing method you can remove them
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closed Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();

    initialize(new Gamekeeper(this),config);
}

@Override
public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (adView.isLoaded()) {
                    adView.show();
                    requestNewInterstitial();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    adView.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

}
```

`
Then in youre core java file youre need to handle the PlayServices.

```
public class Gamekeeper extends Game{
    public static PlayServices playServices;

    public Gamekeeper (PlayServices playServices){
        this.playServices = playServices;
    }
}
```

So in youre game whenever you want to call the Ad use this:

```
Gamekeeper.playServices.showOrLoadInterstital();
```

Thats all. 
Just don't forget to make some [proper thing](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#place_an_adview_in_your_main_activity_layout):

1.Download Google Play services.

2.Include and reference the Google Play services library project.

3.Modify the manifest.